# Parse: Updating relation on user in Local Datastore

Tags: ios, parse-server, local-datastore, pfrelation

I am developing an app where I have a user who has some favourite objects. These favourites are currently modelled by a PFRelation on the user object.

The app needs to function in offline scenarios, so I'm using the Parse local datastore. I'm finding in my tests that after I've updated the relation with a new (but pinned) object, if the device doesn't get internet connectivity (and thus completes the saveEventually call to save remotely) before app restart that the PFRelation loses the new object. The object is available in the local datastore via query, but the PFRelation no longer has it.

I've pinned the user object, and attempted to fetch it from the local datastore following app restart, but the PFRelation seemingly always loses the newly added object.

Has anybody seen this behaviour or know of a workaround?

Comment: http://blog.parse.com/announcements/moving-on/

Comment: Yeah, thanks. I'm using the open source Parse server; updated tag.